# How to slower the effect of hover over the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, hover, scrollbar

I made a scrollbar for a `div` (`#test`). Here is my CSS code:

```
#test {
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-height: 100vh; 
  width: 150px;
  transition: overflow-y 1s linear;
}
#test:hover {
  overflow-y: auto; 
  max-height: 100vh; 
  width: 150px;
}
```

Its changing from overflow hidden to overflow auto properly, but I want that effect to appear slowly. How to do that? I read something with transition but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can use slim scroller for this, http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: if you are  using jquery/ javascript you can use setTimeout



 `var delay=1000, setTimeoutConst;
    $('#test').on('hover', function() {
         setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
                //do something
         }, delay);
    }, function(){
         clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );

      });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to animate the overflow properties with css transitions or animations, since there are no in-between states for `hidden` and `auto` to interpolate.

However, it might be possible to achieve your desired effect by setting the overflow property to a fixed value and play with animatable properties like width and height like so:

```css
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #79a7a7;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.foo:hover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #99e7e7;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
hover me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property can't be animated with CSS.

Check the list of elements you can animate [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
.scroll-bar-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
.scroll-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 295px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .4em; 
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar,
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  overflow:visible;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
}
.cover-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;;
  height: 100%;  
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: .4em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
.scroll-bar-wrap:hover .cover-bar {
   opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-bar-wrap">
  <div class="scroll-box">
    <p>Consectet adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Consectet adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cover-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Szymek : Please do try the above code. Hope it works.